# Calc aggregates across continuous groups of values in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

This is something that would probably be pretty easy to code a solution, but harder to accomplish in straight SQL. I may have to give up and code a routine that scans through the table.

I have a table of user status values with start and end dates that is like this:

```
create table #t (userid int4, status varchar(15), start_time date, end_time date);

insert into #t values
(1, 'Active', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-20'),
(1, 'Active', '2019-08-20', '2019-08-22'),
(1, 'Active', '2019-08-22', '2019-09-22'),
(1, 'Inactive', '2019-09-22', '2019-10-22'),
(1, 'At Risk', '2019-10-22', '2019-11-22'),
(1, 'Lapsed', '2019-11-22', '2019-12-08'),
(1, 'Active', '2019-12-08', '2019-12-18'),
(1, 'Active', '2019-12-18', '2020-01-11'),
(1, 'Active', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-15'),
(1, 'Active', '2020-01-15', '2020-02-15'),
(1, 'Inactive', '2020-02-15', '2020-03-15')
;
```

I'm trying to summarized to min/max dates for each continuous group of status values (when sorted by start_time), as shown below:

[image: summarized status table]

I've been trying to get there by using window functions in Redshift, but I cannot partition based on status as that seems to group the statuses together and I end up with "Active" from 2019-08-15 to 2020-02-15.

Comment: I'm on my phone so it will take Ages for me to type the query. But the methodology you need is known as gaps-and-islands.  It is a relatively elegant way of using windowed functions to identify the groups you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a so-called gaps-and-islands approach. Written on my phone so untested.  But you should be able to search SO for that key-phrase.

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY userid
            ORDER BY start
      )
        AS row_userid_start,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY userid, status
            ORDER BY start
      )
        AS row_userid_status_start
  FROM
    #t
)
SELECT
  userid,
  status,
  MIN(start)   AS start,
  MAX(end)     AS end
FROM
  sorted
GROUP BY
  userid,
  status,
  row_userid_status_start - row_userid_start
```